# Interface methods with variable argument types

Tags: java, oop, generics, design-patterns, solid-principles

I have java interface and class implementations that have need for different arguments when invoking similar behavior. Which of the following is mostly appropriate?

In first option I have different classes inherit common behavior from base interface and all differences are only implemented directly in the classes and not in interface. This one seems most appropriate, but I have to do manual type-cast in the code.

```
public class VaryParam1 {

    static Map<VehicleType, Vehicle> list = new HashMap<>();

    static List<Car> carsList = new ArrayList<>();
    static List<TruckWithTrailer> trucksList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        list.put(VehicleType.WITHOUT_TRAILER, new Car());
        list.put(VehicleType.WITH_TRAILER, new TruckWithTrailer());

        //violates LSP?
        ((Car)list.get(VehicleType.WITHOUT_TRAILER)).paint(1); //ok - but needed manual cast
        ((TruckWithTrailer)list.get(VehicleType.WITH_TRAILER)).paint(1, "1"); //ok - but needed manual cast

        carsList.add(new Car());
        trucksList.add(new TruckWithTrailer());

        //Does not violate LSP
        carsList.get(0).paint(1);
        trucksList.get(0).paint(1, "1");
    }
}

enum VehicleType {
    WITHOUT_TRAILER,
    WITH_TRAILER;
}

interface Vehicle{
    //definition of all common methods
    void drive();
    void stop();
}

class Car implements Vehicle {

    public void paint(int vehicleColor) {
        System.out.println(vehicleColor);
    }

    @Override
    public void drive() {}

    @Override
    public void stop() {}
}

class TruckWithTrailer implements Vehicle {

    public void paint(int vehicleColor, String trailerColor) {
        System.out.println(vehicleColor + trailerColor);
    }

    @Override
    public void drive() {}

    @Override
    public void stop() {}
}
```

In second option I have moved methods one level up to the interface, but now I need to implement behavior with UnsupportedOpException. This looks like code smell. In code, I don't have to do manual casting, but I also have possibility to call methods that will produce exception in run time - no compile time checking. This is not that big problem - only this methods with exception that look like code smell. Is this way of implementation best practice?

```
public class VaryParam2 {

    static Map<VehicleType, Vehicle> list = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        list.put(VehicleType.WITHOUT_TRAILER, new Car());
        list.put(VehicleType.WITH_TRAILER, new TruckWithTrailer());

        list.get(VehicleType.WITHOUT_TRAILER).paint(1); //works
        list.get(VehicleType.WITH_TRAILER).paint(1, "1"); //works

        list.get(VehicleType.WITHOUT_TRAILER).paint(1, "1"); //ok - exception - passing trailer when no trailer - no compile time check!
        list.get(VehicleType.WITH_TRAILER).paint(1); //ok - exception - calling trailer without trailer args - no compile time check!
    }
}

enum VehicleType {
    WITHOUT_TRAILER,
    WITH_TRAILER;
}

interface Vehicle{
    void paint(int vehicleColor);
    void paint(int vehicleColor, String trailerColor);    //code smell - not valid for all vehicles??
}

class Car implements Vehicle {

    @Override
    public void paint(int vehicleColor) {
        System.out.println(vehicleColor);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(int vehicleColor, String trailerColor) {    //code smell ??
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Car has no trailer");
    }
}

class TruckWithTrailer implements Vehicle {

    @Override
    public void paint(int vehicleColor) {  //code smell ??
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("What to do with the trailer?");
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(int vehicleColor, String trailerColor) {
        System.out.println(vehicleColor + trailerColor);
    }
}
```

Here I used generics in order to have common method in interface, and parameter type is decided in each class implementation. Problem here is that I have unchecked calls to paint. This is more-less similar to problem of direct casting in option 1. Bur here I also have possibility to call methods that I should not be able to!

```
public class VaryParam3 {

    static Map<VehicleType, Vehicle> list = new HashMap<>();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        list.put(VehicleType.WITHOUT_TRAILER, new Car());
        list.put(VehicleType.WITH_TRAILER, new TruckWithTrailer());

        list.get(VehicleType.WITHOUT_TRAILER).paint(new VehicleParam());    //works but unchecked call
        list.get(VehicleType.WITH_TRAILER).paint(new TruckWithTrailerParam());    //works but unchecked call

        list.get(VehicleType.WITHOUT_TRAILER).paint(new TruckWithTrailerParam()); //works but should not!
        list.get(VehicleType.WITH_TRAILER).paint(new VehicleParam());   //ClassCastException in runtime - ok but no compile time check
    }
}

enum VehicleType {
    WITHOUT_TRAILER,
    WITH_TRAILER;
}

class VehicleParam {
    int vehicleColor;
}

class TruckWithTrailerParam extends VehicleParam {
    String trailerColor;
}

interface Vehicle<T extends VehicleParam>{
    void paint(T param);
}

class Car implements Vehicle<VehicleParam> {

    @Override
    public void paint(VehicleParam param) {
        System.out.println(param.vehicleColor);
    }
}

class TruckWithTrailer implements Vehicle<TruckWithTrailerParam> {

    @Override
    public void paint(TruckWithTrailerParam param) {
        System.out.println(param.vehicleColor + param.trailerColor);
    }
}
```

So question is - which of this 3 options is the best one (or if there is some other option I have not found)? In terms of further maintenance, changing etc.

**UPDATE**

I updated the question and now I have paint method that can be called only after object is constructed.

So far this looks like the best option as it is suggested in the post below:

```
public class VaryParam4 {

    static Map<VehicleType, Vehicle> list = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        list.put(VehicleType.WITHOUT_TRAILER, new Car());
        list.put(VehicleType.WITH_TRAILER, new TruckWithTrailer());

        list.get(VehicleType.WITHOUT_TRAILER).paint(new PaintConfigObject());    //works but can pass trailerColor (even if null) that is not needed
        list.get(VehicleType.WITH_TRAILER).paint(new PaintConfigObject());    //works
    }
}

enum VehicleType {
    WITHOUT_TRAILER,
    WITH_TRAILER;
}

class PaintConfigObject {
    int vehicleColor;
    String trailerColor;
}

interface Vehicle{
    void paint(PaintConfigObject param);
}

class Car implements Vehicle {

    @Override
    public void paint(PaintConfigObject param) {
        //param.trailerColor will never be used here but it's passed in param
        System.out.println(param.vehicleColor);
    }
}

class TruckWithTrailer implements Vehicle {

    @Override
    public void paint(PaintConfigObject param) {
        System.out.println(param.vehicleColor + param.trailerColor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is the number of doors relevant to *driving* a vehicle? Surely this is something determined at construction time?

Comment: I will update example with paint() method where car has paint(vehiclecolor) and truck has pain(vehiclecolor, trailercolor). Colors are determined in runtime, after vehicles are already constructed.

Comment: With your first example, you imply that you already know the type of the `Vehicle`, based on the enum value you pass. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. actually the use case for current paint method is that somebody will give me id of vehicle and paints (either vehicle paint or vehicle and trailer paint). Based on this I know when I select vehicle from the map, it is either with or without trailer.

Comment: @bojanv55 Take a look at my updated answer. I believe it covers all aspects of your question now. Do let me know if you have any further clarifications or if you see any issues with following that approach now?

Comment: @bojanv55 If you know the type already, can't you use 2 separated maps for each type of vehicle? Then based on the arguments you get passed you retrieve an object from either map.

Comment: @JornVernee idea seems ok for this example, but if i need to iterate vehicles and call common operation on them (eg. stop()) I would have to iterate over both maps.

Comment: @bojanv55 You could hide that implementation in a class that let's you retrieve either type, but iterate over both as well. A class that has 2 (or more) maps, but also provides a view as if they were 1 map.

Comment: @JornVernee seems to me that this option is more less the same as manual type casting, just now moved to the other class with separate methods.

Comment: @bojanv55 That's true. The main difference is that the other never has to cast, and actually never ambiguates the types. It always remembers the distinction internally.

Comment: Why does a vehicle not already know it's color/s? Seems like a case of low cohesion. Or is `paint` used for changing the vehicle color/s?

Comment: @weston it's used to change the color.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A better option would be to get rid of the *overloaded* versions of the `drive` method and pass whatever information is required by the subclasses in the constructor instead :

```
interface Vehicle{
    void drive();
}

class Car implements Vehicle {
    private int numberOfDoors;

    public Car(int numberOfDoors) {
         this.numberOfDoors = numberOfDoors;
     }

    public void drive() {
        System.out.println(numberOfDoors);
    }
}


class TruckWithTrailer implements Vehicle {
    private int numberOfDoors;
    private int numberOfTrailers;

    public TruckWithTrailer(int numberOfDoors,numberOfTrailers) {
          this.numberOfDoors = numberOfDoors;
          this.numberOfTrailers = numberOfTrailers;
    }

    @Override
    public void drive() {
        System.out.println(numberOfDoors + numberOfTrailers);
    }
}
```

---

Addressing your comment regarding the `paint` being decided at runtime, you can add a `paint` method to vehicle that takes variable arguments :

```
interface Vehicle{
    void drive();
    void paint(String ...colors);
}
```

---

As discussed in the comments, if the number of arguments to be used in the paint method varies for different vehicle types, define a class called `PaintSpecification` that contains attributes such as `vehcileColor`, `trailerColor` and change the `paint` method to have an argument of type `PaintSpecification` instead.

```
interface Vehicle{
    void drive();
    void paint(PaintSpecification spec);
}
```

The advantage of all the above approaches is that all `Vehicle` implementations adhere to a single contract allowing you to perform operations such as adding all your `Vehicle` instances to a `List` and calling the `paint` method on them one by one regardless of their type.

Comment: What if the params are not known at the construction time?

Comment: @bojanv55 Then you don't create the object till you have the required params?

Comment: Instead of drive() lets say it is paint() method. But color will be determined afterwards. You already have vehicles in the list and then you decide to paint them. you have for car: paint(vehiclecolor) and for truck: paint (vehiclecolor, trailercolor).

Comment: @bojanv55 I don't see you mention such a requirement anywhere in your initial question. You use a paint method with `varargs` in this case in `Vehicle`. (i.e `public void paint(int ..colors)`)

Comment: @bojanv55 See edit. I hope you won't add a new requirement now . (You kind of already answered your own question with the title of your question) :)

Comment: I had to change this a bit, since now I have int and String at same time, so variable args is pobably not ok for this use case?

Comment: @bojanv55 I am sorry to say this but if you don't adhere to a fixed contract, the `interface` is a bit useless since there is no real *Polymorphism* left in your code.

Comment: I agree. I just want to find the best possible option here (since I'm possibly missing something). I assume then that option 1 is the best one in this case?

Comment: @bojanv55 Exactly, think about the client having to deal with a list of `Vehicle`. Would he be able to paint them without knowing their concrete type?

Comment: @bojanv55 Do you mean option 1 in your code? No it's not. You might as well treat a `Car` and `Trailer` as unrelated objects as you are not adhering to a contract anyway.

Comment: @CKing I suppose you missed comment in option 1 : //definition of all common methods in the interface. I removed all common methods from the sample

Comment: One option could perhaps to have something like `paint(PaintSpecification spec)` where the specification is a configuration object that can cover all cases. The `Vehicule` could then only use what it understands from the specification. The one that constructs the specification needs to know the type of vehicule though.

Comment: @plalx Yes that would make sense; however, the bottom line is that the OP either adheres to a fixed contract or he maintains two unrelated `Map` of objects.

Comment: @plalx Thats similar to my option 3?

Comment: @bojanv55 Similar, but you shouldn't have any polymorphism or you break the LSP. In a more complex problem where you could paint different areas in different colors etc, you may find a common abstraction for all paintables. A `Paintable` may have a `Shape` for instance. A vehicule could be constituted of many `Paintable` components (e.g. `getPaintables()`). The paint contract would define which paintable and which part of their shape gets painted, etc.

Comment: @plalx can you please post some example?

Comment: @bojanv55 Just use one data structure where some members are declared as `Optional<T>`.

Comment: @plalx isn't this more-less the same as using only `void paint(int vehicleColor, String trailerColor);` and when need to paint car I call `paint(vehicleColor, null)` ?

Comment: @bojanv55 No or you will be breaking the contract for every new type of vehicules that may need additionnal options.

Comment: @bojanv55 It's not that complicated. Just define an interface called `PaintSpecifiation` with multiple implementations.

Comment: @plalx so in my 3rd option i should change `class VehicleParam {
    int vehicleColor;
}` to `class PaintSpecification { int vehicleColor; String trailerColor; }` ? - and here trailerColor would be null when passed to vehicle without trailer?

Comment: @bojanv55 More like `PaintSpecification { int vehicleColor; Optional<String> trailerColor; }`, but yeah that could be a simple option. It's hard to tell without a real-world use case what design you should be using.

Comment: @plalx thanks for suggestions. I still think that option 1 is better, since here I'm passing trailerColor param (even if null or not existant) to object that has not a clue about what the trailer is.

Comment: @bojanv55 You break LSP with option 1.

Comment: @bojanv55 In this case use 2 lists for `Car` and `Truck` and implement `paint` on both of them, not on `Vehicule`.

Comment: @bojanv55 Once again, I am sorry to say this but it looks like what you are trying to say is *my option is good right? I know it's good. It's better than any of the options you guys are talking about*. There is something both plax and I are trying to explain to you with this long comment chain but you seem to miss the point. The L in SOLID principles will be violated with option 1 so it's not better in any way.

Comment: @CKing how is it violated when drive method is not in interface but only in subclasses?

Comment: @MarkoKraljevic LSP is not only about interface methods but being able to substitute one type for another. A trailer and car is a Vehicle but you need to cast to a subclass type to access trailer and car specific methods. This violates LSP.

Comment: @CKing i dont think this specific case violates LSP. Here Vehicle is actually casted to specific type before using. Basically we are calling method on TruckWithTrailer and Car and not on the Vehicle itself.

Comment: @CKing so if I use in 1st example 2 Lists eg. `List<Car> carsList` and `List<TruckWithTrailer> trucksList` that wouldnt violate LSP?

Comment: @bojanv55 Yes. That's right. But again, it would kind of make the `Vehicle` interface obsolete since classes can't work with it without casting anyway.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136033/discussion-on-answer-by-cking-interface-with-variable-argument-types).

Answer (score 2):

> but I have to do manual type-cast in the code.

It's because you lost the type information that you obviously need.

Your client code depends on concrete type information, because your paint method depends on concrete types.

If your client code should not be aware of the concrete `Vehicle` types, the `Vehicle` interface should be designed in a way that does not need concrete type information. E.g.

```
public void paint();
```

This would also mean that each `Vehicle` instance must have all information that it needs to paint itself. You could give the implementations **`color` properties**.

```
public class Car implements Vehicle {

  private int color = 0; // Default color

  public void paint() {
    System.out.println(color);
  }

  public void setColor(int color){
     // maybe some validation first
     this.color = color;
  }
}
```

or pass them to the `paint` method:

```
 public void paint(Color color)
```

If you need to pass even more properties you can create a `PaintContext` class and pass it to the paint method.

**What else can you do?**

If you want to keep your code as it is you must recreate the type infromation in some way.

I see the following solutions:

- **instanceof** checks with downcast (you already tried that)
- **Adapter-Pattern**
- **Visitor-Pattern**

**Adapter-Pattern**

```
interface Vehicle {
    public <T extends Vehicle> T getAdapter(Class<T> adapterClass);
}

class Car implements Vehicle {

    @Override
    public <T extends Vehicle> T getAdapter(Class<T> adapterClass) {
        if(adapterClass.isInstance(this)){
            return adapterClass.cast(this);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Your client code will then look like this:

```
Vehicle vehicle = ...;

Car car = vehicle.getAdapter(Car.class);
if(car != null){
    // the vehicle can be adapted to a car
    car.paint(1);
}
```

**Pros of the Adapter-Pattern**

- You move the `instanceof` checks from the client code into the adapter. Thus the client code will be more refactoring-safe. E.g. imagine the following client code:

  ```
    if(vehicle instanceof Car){
       // ...
    } else if(vehicle instanceof TruckWithTrailer){
       // ...
    }
  ```

  Think about what will happen if you refactor your code to `TruckWithTrailer extends Car`
- The adapter must not return itself. The concrete `Vehicle` might instantiate another object that let it look like the adapter type.

  ```
    public <T extends Vehicle> T getAdapter(Class<T> adapterClass) {
        if(Car.class.isAssignableFrom(adapterClass)){
            return new CarAdapter(this)
        }
        return null;
    }
  ```

**Cons of the Adapter-Pattern**

- The [cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) of client code increases when you add more and more implementations of `Vehicle` (a lot of if-else statements).

**Visitor-Pattern**

```
interface Vehicle {
    public void accept(VehicleVisitor vehicleVisitor);
}

interface VehicleVisitor {
    public void visit(Car car);
    public void visit(TruckWithTrailer truckWithTrailer);
}
```

The implementations of car will then decide which method of the `VihicleVisitor` should be invoked.

```
class Car implements Vehicle {

    public void paint(int vehicleColor) {
        System.out.println(vehicleColor);
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(VehicleVisitor vehicleVisitor) {
        vehicleVisitor.visit(this);
    }
}
```

Your client code must then provide a `VehicleVisitor`

```
    Vehicle vehicle = ...;
    vehicle.accept(new VehicleVisitor() {

        public void visit(TruckWithTrailer truckWithTrailer) {
            truckWithTrailer.paint(1, "1");

        }

        public void visit(Car car) {
            car.paint(1);
        }
    });
```

**Pros of the Visitor-Pattern**

- Separation of type specific logic in separate methods

**Cons of the Visitor-Pattern**

- New types require the visitor interface to change and all implementations of the visitor must be changed as well.

---

PS: With more information about the context of your code there might be other solutions.

Comment: How do you pass parameters 1 and "1" to visitor pattern's `VehicleVisitor`, since those could always be variable? Then you are back to the source of the problem.

Comment: @MarkoKraljevic I would either create an own class and pass them through constructor args or in case of an anonymous class use final vars. I would prefer creating an own class anyway, beause it makes the code better testable. I just used an anonymous class in my example to keep it easy and short.